# graph-tools BFS search speed up

Tags: python-2.7, networkx, graph-tool

I have tried to set up graph-tools BFS search on a ubuntu system. Due to a bug I have been forced to use the `graph_tools.bfs_search()` instead of `graph_tools.bfs_iterator`.

So I did set up a minimal class as mentioned in the examples inheriting from `graph_tools.BFSVisitor`.

The goal of this is to track all of the edge source nodes and edge action values pairs reachable from a specific node in a graph and store them in a numpy array, such that the array will have the following dimensions: `(num_nodes, num_actions)` where `num_actions` is equal to the maximum out-degree in the graph.

The function does its jobs but accessing the edge PropertyMap `self.edge_action[edge]` of the graph in order to retrieve the edge action is a huuge bottleneck and significantly slows down my code. But since I tried to use graph-tools only for speed in the first place, I am a little bit stuck right now.

Am I missing on something about the graph-tools library or is there no way to speed this up? Otherwise I might as well just go back to networkx and try to find the fastest way there.
I simply cannot think of a way to avoid using this pythonic loop to access edge actions in order to use the c++ power of graph-tools.

Here my simple class:

```
class SetIterator(gt.BFSVisitor):
    def __init__(self, action, safe_set):
        """
        action: gt.PropertyMap
            edge property representing edge action
        safe_set: np.array
            array used to store safe node, action pairs
        """
        self.edge_action = action
        self.ea = self.edge_action
        self.safe_set = safe_set

    def discover_vertex(self, u):
        """
        Invoked on first encounter of vertex.
        Parameters
        ----------
        u:  gt.Vertex

        """
        self.safe_set[int(u), 0] = True

    def examine_edge(self, e):
        """
        Called when edge is checked
        Parameters
        ----------
        e:  gt.Edge

        """
        # TODO This one line is bottleneck of code
        self.safe_set[int(e.source()), self.ea[e]] = True
```

Comment: It would certainly be useful to [profile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) your code so that you can pinpoint exactly where the "hotspots" are. For example, indexing will take time (as in, fetch the value of this key from a dictionary), let alone having to access multiple indices. That `int` casting might have something to do with the delays too.

Comment: I profiled the code, that's why I know and mentioned above that the bottleneck is in the last line. More specific accessing the edge-action via the propertymap `self.ea`. So, I wonder if there is a better way in graph-tools to keep track of edge attributes

Comment: I struggle to see how this is a graph-tool problem since `edge_action` and `safe_set` are part of the visitor's local memory. But in any case, if you are prepared to consider an alternative data structure for those variables, perhaps you will get the speedup you seek. Would a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) work for that `safe_set`'s indexing for example? (Please see [this link](http://kmike.ru/python-data-structures/) as well).